# R: Sometimes system.file not working as documented

Tags: r

The `system.file` commands in my package examples sometimes fail unpredictably, while passing at other times.  I do not understand why.

I typically use:

```
> system.file("examples", "trees.xml", package="RNeXML", mustWork=TRUE)
```

which usually works, but sometimes fails (even in an interactive session):

```
Error in system.file("examples", "trees.xml", package = "RNeXML", mustWork = TRUE) :
```

no file found

when it is failing, I can get this to work:

```
> system.file("examples", "trees.xml", lib.loc = .libPaths()[1], package="RNeXML", mustWork=TRUE)
[1] "/home/cboettig/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RNeXML/examples/trees.xml"
```

Which doesn't make any sense to me, because the documentation of `system.file` says that it checks `libPaths` automatically if no value for `lib.loc` is provided.

So why does it work if I give the `.libPaths()[1]` explicitly?

It seems like explicitly telling my package to use the first path, `.libPaths()[1]`, would be less stable.

Comment: Perhaps a question for the rdevel mailing list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is a [heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug), set `options(error = recover)` and when prompted for a frame number, pick the one that brings you into `system.file`. (For more on what I'm about to explain, see Hadley's [Exceptions and Debugging tutorial](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html).) Then step through using the debugger and determine if `packagePath` gets loaded correctly using `find.package(package, lib.loc, quiet = TRUE)`. I inspected this latter function and couldn't find anything immediately wrong, so it may be something system-specific. Could you post your `sessionInfo()`?

If `packagePath` is fine, then the answer lies somewhere in the rest of `system.file`'s body:

```
FILES <- file.path(packagePath, ...)
present <- file.exists(FILES)
if (any(present))
   FILES[present]
else ""
```

This would make life very hard for us since I doubt there are problems with any of these functions. If `packagePath` is not what you expect, you can use the `recover` frame number prompt again to dive back into `system.file`, and this time type `debug(find.package)` so you can step through that function. Inspect `dirs` and `paths` after the `for (lib in lib.loc)`, and step through the few `if`s that follow.

If none of these work, and you don't spot any mischief (which is very hard with the transparency of a step-by-step debugger), you can always try to [`dump.frames`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/debugger.html) and upload the file for us. I am not sure how useful it will be, since even if we install the same packages, there may be path issues, but it's worth a shot.

Finally, if you don't care about all of the above, a hack that works would be:

```
trees_path <- ""
for(lib in .libPaths()) {
  trees_path <- system.file("examples", "trees.xml", lib.loc = lib, package="RNeXML", mustWork = FALSE)
  if (trees_path != "") break;
}
if (trees_path == "") stop("examples/trees.xml not found using any library paths")
```